# Scripts section and minified files in ASP NET Core (.NET 5.0)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor

I have a WEB application with Razor pages. I'm using "environment" tag to specify full and minified JS file versions. Like this:

```
@section Scripts {

<environment include="Development">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/payments.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>

<environment exclude="Development">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/payments.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
}
```

And in main layout:

```
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
```

So, nothing special.
Because I have page specific JS files - I should add them on every page with "environment" tag. Every new page I (or somebody) will add this tag if not forget :)

Is it possible to do something like...
When scripts section is render get all scripts in it and if some "replaceable" variable found - replace with minified version? In a page I will add scripts section with specific variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/payments.js" asp-append-version="true" replaceable="true"></script>
```

But how to do this?

PS I know about fallback parameter but I think it is better to not use it in this case.

Comment: I still couldn't understand your requirement. What you will do if the script tag contain the replaceable attribute? What you mean about replace with minified version? Replace what value?

Comment: In this case script file name should be changed from payments.js to payments.min.js
A final goal - make some rule of replacement in one place not in all pages, not in every new page.